# Resizing Facebook Connect login pop up window

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to resize the login pop-up window that shows up after clicking on a facebook login button? I am able to connect and logout completely from Facebook but what i need right now is to make the login pop-up window a little bigger than how it is being shown. I am using FB.Connect.requireSession in connecting to facebook after clicking on a login button. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Facebook SDK for JavaScript](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) documentation, you can use the [`FB.Canvas.setSize`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/) method.

> When determining the Canvas Height automatically the height it can only be increased, **not decreased**.

and as an example:

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 640, height: 480 });
```

Or, if you know your content will change size but you don't know exactly when, you can take a look at the [`FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow/) method.